# Mirror symmetry for K3 fibered Calabi-Yau threefolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-geometry, calabi-yau

By a K3 fibered Calabi-Yau threefold, I mean a smooth projective threefold $X$ with trivial canonical class and
$h^{1,0}(X) =h^{2,0}(X)  = 0$ that has a fibration $X \rightarrow \mathbb P^1$ whose generic fibers are smooth K3 surfaces (to be denoted by $S_X$)

I gathered some examples of mirror pairs of those K3-fibered CY threefolds.

Borcea--Voisin CY's,

CY double coverings over some quasi-Fano threefolds in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.02489).

From these examples, I observed:

> In these examples of mirror pairs of  K3-fibered CY threefolds X, Y. Their generic K3 fibers are K3 mirrors (in the definition of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9502005)).
> In concrete words, there are embeddings lattices $\phi_X: Pic(S_X) \rightarrow L$, $\phi_Y: Pic(S_Y) \rightarrow L$ to K3 lattice $L$ of rank 22 and signature $(3, 19)$ such that
> $L = im(\phi_X) \oplus im(\phi_Y) \oplus U$ ,where $U$ is a unimodular hyperbolic plane  in $L$.

My question is:

> 1. Are there other examples of  mirror pairs of K3-fibered CY threefolds that support or fail this observation.

> 2. If other known examples also support this observation, Is this observation expected from any kind of theories of mirror symmetry of Calabi-Yau threefolds with K3 fibration?

Answer (score 5):

Morally speaking, a K3 fibration on one side of the mirror correspondence should correspond to a K3 *degeneration* on the other side. In the physics literature, I think this observation goes back to studies of the F-theory/heterotic duality in the '90s; some coauthors and I wrote a paper with [a more combinatorial take](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3277931) that describes how to understand and generate toric examples (though in the toric case, identifying the appropriate polarizing lattice can be subtle). Studies of Tyurin degeneration, including the Nam-Hoon Lee paper you linked and the work of Doran-Harder-Thompson, should give you another perspective on the degeneration/fibration duality.